# Is there a way to detect if you have permissions to publish via npm before attempting an actual publish?

Tags: npm

I would like to detect if I have permissions to run `npm publish` without actually doing a publish. I tried `npm publish --dry-run`, but it runs successfully even if I don't have permissions. It looks like that's only useful to show what the tarball would look like.

Is there a way to do a permission check as well?